# Java, MySQL Connection kill by input data

Tags: java, mysql

I try to read CSV files into a MySQL-DB but the files have more than 40000 lines. The CSV-Reader is not the problem. And I can write the lines into the MySQL-DB. But when I will read and write all lines of the CSV my Connection to the MySQL-Server gets killed in the process. The Program reads and writes successfully more than 1000 lines before my connection ends. I get the following errors:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status server
```

Or

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet successfully received from the server was 328.971 milliseconds ago.  The last packet sent successfully to the server was 328.971 milliseconds ago.
```

Do you have any idea why this is?

I wrote in the catch-block a method that renews the connection but it read few rows and the connection was kill again.

The Code to get the lines from the CSV and load into the MySQL-DB

```
kptoolsDB.setAutoCommit(false);
dateiImpDB.setAutoCommit(false);
while(prop != null && this.isInterrupted() == false)
{
    vertragsID = null;
    rufNr = null;

    try {
        setDaten(prop);
        kptoolsDB.commit();
        dateiImpDB.commit();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.toString(), this);
        setDBConnections(hilfstabelle);
        try {
            setDaten(prop);
            kptoolsDB.commit();
            dateiImpDB.commit();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.toString(), this);
            setDBConnections(hilfstabelle);
        }
    }

    view.setProgessBarVal(count);

    prop = reader.getNextLine();
    count++;
}
kptoolsDB.setAutoCommit(true);
dateiImpDB.setAutoCommit(true);
```

The method `setDaten()`

```
private void setDaten(Properties prop) throws SQLException
{
    ResultSet rst;

    rst = statKPTools.executeQuery("select rechnungsID from isimrechnungeintrag where rawcdr = " + prop.get("i_rawcdr") + ";");
    if(rst.next())
    {
        log.log(LogLevel.INFO, "Die CDR-Nummer " + prop.get("i_rawcdr") + " ist schon eingetragen!", this);
    } else {
        rst.close();

        rufNr = "+" + prop.get("MSISDN").toString().replace("-", "").replace(" ", "");

        if(!pruefeRufnummer(rufNr))
        {
            setRufNrNichtGefunden(rufNr);
        } else {
            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm");
            Date datum = null;
            try {
                datum = sdf.parse(prop.get("call_start_datetime").toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.toString(), this);
            }

            prepSetRechEintrag.setInt(1, 5);
            prepSetRechEintrag.setLong(3, vertragsID);
            prepSetRechEintrag.setDate(2, new java.sql.Date(datum.getTime()));
            prepSetRechEintrag.executeUpdate();

            rst = statKPTools.executeQuery("select max(ID) from rechnungseintrag;");
            if(rst.next())
            {
                prepSetISIMRechEintag.setLong(1, rst.getLong(1));
                prepSetISIMRechEintag.setDouble(2, new Double(prop.get("VK netto").toString().replace(",", ".")));
                prepSetISIMRechEintag.setDouble(3, new Double(prop.get("EK netto").toString().replace(",", ".")));
                prepSetISIMRechEintag.setInt(4, new Integer(prop.get("event_id").toString()));
                prepSetISIMRechEintag.setString(5, prop.get("event").toString());
                prepSetISIMRechEintag.setLong(6, new Long(prop.get("i_rawcdr").toString()));
                prepSetISIMRechEintag.executeUpdate();

                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                cal.setTime(datum);

                prepInsertVolumHilfe.setLong(1, vertragsID);
                prepInsertVolumHilfe.setInt(2, new Integer(prop.get("event_id").toString()));
                prepInsertVolumHilfe.setString(3, prop.get("event").toString());
                prepInsertVolumHilfe.setLong(4, new Long(prop.get("charged_quantity").toString()));
                prepInsertVolumHilfe.setInt(5, cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
                prepInsertVolumHilfe.setInt(6, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
                prepInsertVolumHilfe.executeUpdate();
            }
        }
    }
    rst.close();
}
```

The MySQL-Connection Class

```
package DatenbankConector;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import EigeneExceptions.FehlendeLoginDaten;
import Enums.LogLevel;
import Enums.MySQLDatenbanken;
import Hilfsklassen.Logger;

public class MYSQLDB {

private static MYSQLDB loginDB = null;
private static MYSQLDB kptoolsDB = null;
private static MYSQLDB datenImpDB = null;
private static String loginUser = null;
private static String loginPass = null;

private Logger log = Logger.getInstance();

private Connection connect;
private String dbHost = "XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"; // Hostname
private String dbPort = "3306";      // Port -- Standard: 3306
private String logindbUser = "******";     // Login-Datenbankuser
private String logindbPass = "********";      // Login-Datenbankpasswort
private boolean kannStarten = false;
private MySQLDatenbanken dbEnum;

private MYSQLDB(MySQLDatenbanken db)
{
    String strConnect = "";
    dbEnum = db;

    switch(db)
    {
        case LOGIN_DB:
            strConnect = "jdbc:mysql://"+dbHost+":"+ dbPort+"/logindb?"+"user="+logindbUser+"&"+"password="+logindbPass;
            break;
        case KPTOOLS_DB:
            strConnect = "jdbc:mysql://"+dbHost+":"+ dbPort+"/kptools?"+"user="+loginUser+"&"+"password="+loginPass;
            break;
        case DATEI_IMP_DB:
            strConnect = "jdbc:mysql://"+dbHost+":"+ dbPort+"/dateiimporter?"+"user="+loginUser+"&"+"password="+loginPass;
            break;
    }

    try
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        connect = DriverManager.getConnection(strConnect);
        kannStarten = true;
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.toString(), this);
        kannStarten = false;
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.toString(), this);
        kannStarten = false;
    }
}

/**
 * Gibt eine Instanz von MYSQLDB zurueck.
 * 
 * @param db Angabe welche Datenbank aufgerufen werden soll.
 * 
 * @return ein MYSQLDB Objekt
 * 
 * @throws FehlendeLoginDaten Fehler fals noch keine Logindaten gesetzt wurden.
 */
public static MYSQLDB getInstance(MySQLDatenbanken db) throws FehlendeLoginDaten
{
    MYSQLDB obj = null;

    switch(db)
    {
        case LOGIN_DB:
            if(loginDB == null)
            {
                loginDB = new MYSQLDB(MySQLDatenbanken.LOGIN_DB);
                obj = loginDB;
            } else {
                obj = loginDB;
            }
            break;
        case KPTOOLS_DB:
            if(kptoolsDB == null)
            {
                if(loginUser != null && loginPass != null)
                {
                    kptoolsDB = new MYSQLDB(MySQLDatenbanken.KPTOOLS_DB);
                    obj = kptoolsDB;
                } else {
                    throw new FehlendeLoginDaten();
                }
            } else {
                obj = kptoolsDB;
            }
            break;
        case DATEI_IMP_DB:
            if(datenImpDB == null)
            {
                if(loginUser != null && loginPass != null)
                {
                    datenImpDB = new MYSQLDB(MySQLDatenbanken.DATEI_IMP_DB);
                    obj = datenImpDB;
                } else {
                    throw new FehlendeLoginDaten();
                }
            } else {
                obj = datenImpDB;
            }
            break;
    }

    return obj;
}

/**
 * Gibt eine Instanz von MYSQLDB zurueck.
 * 
 * @param db Angabe welche Datenbank aufgerufen werden soll.
 * @param user Benutzername für den Datenbanklogin
 * @param pass Passwort für den Datenbanklogin
 * 
 * @return ein MYSQLDB Objekt
 * 
 * @throws FehlendeLoginDaten Fehler fals noch keine Logindaten gesetzt wurden.
 */
public static MYSQLDB getInstance(MySQLDatenbanken db, String user, String pass) throws FehlendeLoginDaten
{
    MYSQLDB objekt = null;
    loginUser = user;
    loginPass = pass;

    switch(db)
    {
        case LOGIN_DB:
            if(loginDB == null)
            {
                loginDB = new MYSQLDB(MySQLDatenbanken.LOGIN_DB);
                objekt = loginDB;
            } else {
                objekt = loginDB;
            }
            break;
        case KPTOOLS_DB:
            if(kptoolsDB == null)
            {
                if(loginUser != null && loginPass != null)
                {
                    kptoolsDB = new MYSQLDB(MySQLDatenbanken.KPTOOLS_DB);
                    objekt = kptoolsDB;
                } else {
                    throw new FehlendeLoginDaten();
                }
            } else {
                objekt = kptoolsDB;
            }
            break;
        case DATEI_IMP_DB:
            if(datenImpDB == null)
            {
                if(loginUser != null && loginPass != null)
                {
                    datenImpDB = new MYSQLDB(MySQLDatenbanken.DATEI_IMP_DB);
                    objekt = datenImpDB;
                } else {
                    throw new FehlendeLoginDaten();
                }
            } else {
                objekt = datenImpDB;
            }
            break;
    }

    return objekt;
}

/**
 * Gibt ein Satement Objekt du einer Datenbank zurueck.
 *   
 * @return ein Statement der Datenbankconektion
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public Statement getStatement() throws SQLException
{
    Statement stat = connect.createStatement();

    return stat;
}

/**
 * Commitet die Datebankaktionen.
 * 
 * @throws SQLException 
 */
public void commit() throws SQLException
{
    this.connect.commit();
}

/**
 * Gibt ein PreparedStatement zu einem SQL-Statement zurueck.
 * 
 * @param sqlString das SQL-Statement
 * @return das PreparedStatement
 */
public PreparedStatement getPreparedStatement(String sqlString)
{
    try {
        return connect.prepareStatement(sqlString);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.toString(), this);
    }

    return null;
}

/**
 * Schließt eine Datenbankconnection.
 */
public void close()
{
    try
    {
        connect.close();

        switch(dbEnum)
        {
            case LOGIN_DB:
                loginDB = null;
                break;
            case KPTOOLS_DB:
                kptoolsDB = null;
                break;
            case DATEI_IMP_DB:
                datenImpDB = null;
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.toString(), this);
    }
}

/**
 * Gibt zurueck ob beim setzen der Datenbankconnektion ein Fehler aufgetreten ist.
 * 
 * @return funktionstuechtig oder nicht
 */
public boolean getKannStarten()
{
    return kannStarten;
}

/**
 * Setzt die Auto-Commit Variable der Datenbankconnektion
 * 
 * @param autocom true = Auto-Commit
 */
public void setAutoCommit(boolean autocom)
{
    try {
        connect.setAutoCommit(autocom);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        log.log(LogLevel.ERROR, e.toString(), this);
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the error logs in your MySQL server. They should tell you why MySQL terminates the connection.

My guess is that the database limits the size of a transaction. Simply put: You're trying to insert too much data at once.

If that's the case, commit the transaction after every 1000 rows.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I commit at every row. Cann you tell me how i edit the transaction size? I have edit the innodb_buffer_pool_size, the innnodb_log_file_size and the key_buffer_size but he dosn't works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 java.sql.SQLException: Could not retrieve transation read-only status
```

Use older version of MySQL .

I tested MySQL-connector  JDBC driver with both Appserv version and appserv-win32-2.5.9

With Appserv 2.6 I get the above error.

With Appserv version 5 it works fine.